# HTTP Client Programming - How to know server have sent all the datas

Tags: http, httpclient

I am new to HTTP client and TCP\IP programming, so my question might be vague to experienced persons but please try to answer it.

I am implementing a HTTP client , after sending request to server I am waiting for a read event(Asynchronous socket) and when the read event comes I am extracting the data using read command and storing it in a local buffer.

Here how to know that the server has sent all the data's so that I can start processing the information?
I am confused at this stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the content can be returned all together or in chunks. When the server knows before hand the length of the payload, it will provide the [Content-Length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) header in the response. But sometimes the server does not know the total length of payload before start transmitting, then it uses the [chunk transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

Comment: Consider content length to be zero. Is it that all the HTTP headers  can be read in a single time? Won't the header informations be sent in two packets? @vtortola

Comment: If the length is 0, means that you can stop reading after you get an empty line: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_messages.htm

Answer (score 0):

The response from the server should contain a http-header which has a field named content-length. you can use that length to determine the amount of data the server should send. And you are done receiving data once the server has sent the given amount

Comment: Consider content length to be zero. Is it that all the HTTP headers  can be read in a single time? Won't the header informations be sent in two packets? @Spooky3d0

Comment: sorry for the delayed response .. shouldnt i get a mail for this ?

Comment: Well yes it is possible so you should probably make sure to wait until you receive a full header ..   but i am quite sure you figured things out by now :)